# How to create a trapezium mainly bending the right side of the rectangle

Tags: svg

This is my svg path. I am trying to achieve trapezium. Left of the rectangle has come out fine. I wanted the same way on the right side. How do I bend it?

```
<path d="M20 20  H 300 V 70 H 10 Z" fill="transparent" style="stroke:black; stroke-width:2"/>
```

This is the image reference of the shape I wanted:
http://amsi.org.au/teacher_modules/C3/C3g37.png

Comment: Do you know what all that letters and numbers in `d` means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want a vertical line best not to use V as that command draws them. I've replaced the V with an L below.

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%">
  <path d="M20 20  H 300 L 310 70 H 10 Z" fill="transparent" style="stroke:black; stroke-width:2"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks. This exactly what I was looking for. I was trying with rectangle shape before I tried with path. how can I move this down retaining the shape? I want to move it down Y axis.

Comment: transform="translate(0, 10)" perhaps.